# Как избежать вложенности в Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

Исходя из того, что `Constraint Layout` создавался чтоб избежать вложености контейнеров(одна из причин), то как тогда избежать вложеность в случае когда нужно разделить `layout` на 2 цвета?

Вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                         android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="192dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Но все равно получается, что мне нужно сделать вложеность

Или не так?

Comment: В вашем примере один уровень вложенности, меньше быть уже не может. В чём тогда проблема?

Comment: @eugeneek Проблема в том, что по задумке гугл `ConstrainLayout` подразумевает только корневой контейнер (сам `ConstraintLayout`), без каких-либо вложенных контейнеров, только виджеты. В вопросе нетрудно заметить 2 вложенных контейнера, тоже `ConstrainLayout`

Comment: Ну ок. Замените вложенные `ConstrainLayout` на просто `View`. Результат будет абсолютно таким же.

Comment: @eugeneek да но я хочу сохранить возможности ConstrainLayout ... Если сделать просто вью так это уже не будет Constrain

Comment: Если вы хотите в них что-то ещё размещать, то размещайте в корневом констрейнте который имеет абсолютно те же возможности. В ответе вам показали пример. Если имеются сложности с каким-то конкретным макетом, то стоило добавить его в вопрос.

Comment: @eugeneek я просто не знал о этих параметрах app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет необходимости делать вложенность, вот пример на основе твоей разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.33"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="192dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="192dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:progress="45"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Результат:

[image: результат]

Comment: Теперь понятно я просто не знал о этих параметрах app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" . Спасибо

Comment: Да, это я знаю спасибо